# Why is there seemingly such a disconnect between the Geonim and the Rishonim?

Tags: halacha, history, talmud-gemara, rishonim, geonim

It seems that there was a disconnect or upheaval of some kind between the times of the *Geonim* and the times of the *Rishonim* and the *hakhamim* that these two eras contained. *Shittoth* regarding *tefila*, *berakhoth*, *kashruth*, and other areas seem to have been practiced in a completely different manner until many *Rishonim* came along and views things differently.

My question is: "What happened? How their understanding of *halakha* be so different? Further, how could the *Gemara* and other literature be viewed so differently between them?"

Comment: I remember there being a Machlokes whether a Rishon can argue on a Gaon or not (Rambam famously holds one can't)

Comment: Can you cite some examples?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - Actually, the Rambam does not hold this way at all and regularly ignores Gaonic legislation not found in the Talmudic literature. See his Haqdama to the Mishne Tora where he rejects the idea of "halakha k'bathra'ei." Kol tuv.

Comment: @SethJ - Tefila = look in the Sidurim of Rasa"G, Rav Amram, and the teshuvoth of Rav Nattronai. You will see berakhoth - with she and malkhuth - which were said regularly, but were later understood by the Rishonim to be berakhoth l'vattala. Berakhoth = see above, but specifically berakhoth were "innovated" after the Sanhedrin by the Geonim, but later ruled to be "asur" to say. Kashruth = Rules of Sh'hitta, Rav Qapah notes in his pirush on the Rambam that halitta seems to have been required by the Gaonim, but not by Rishonim - almost universally. Hope this helps. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist rambam holds one should perform 7alita. so your statement bout it means taht he didnt agree with them or did agree with them?

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3gob - Of course the Rambam required it, but he was a da`ath yahidh among the Rishonim. No one else required it for anything other than particularly bloody meats like kidneys, livers, etc. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist did the rif require it? i know ravad was harsh on him bout it. and most others dont hold like him. but i never seen the rif mentioning it either

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3gob - the point is that Mori Yusuf z"l had no source (he admits this in that section) on which to base his assumption. But seeing that the Rambam required it while all others did not made him think that the Rambam was continuing a Geonic injunction while the other Rishonim had abandoned it. The fact is that the Gemara before us mentions NOTHING of halitta except for livers and other bloody organs, but never regular cuts of meat, and certainly not poultry. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist i think someone mentions on the rambam that there are those who do it and those who dont.

Comment: Maimonist, you might wish to [edit] those examples (in your comment in reply to @SethJ) and/or others in to the question for clarity

Comment: Maimonist, I think @Mori was asking if Rif required it. If Rambam did, but Rif didn't, it is odd to say that it's Geonic - unless there is some explicit Geonic source.

Comment: Also, one of the standard requirements today with meat is entirely of Geonic origin (although it will take a few minutes for my morning coffee to kick in so I can remember which one it is).

Comment: @SethJ Salting within 72 hours is probably what your were thinking of.

Comment: @DoubleAA according to mori gafe7 salting is only 18/24mins then 7alita for 3mins(according to mori 3arusi student of mori gafe7)

Comment: @double, yup...

Comment: @mori, he means salting within 72 hours after washing. Not salting and letting the salt sit for 72 hours. The Geonim required that the washed meat not sit unsalted for 72 hours. They (may have) interpreted an unrelated Gemara to imply that after 72 hours the flesh and blood would harden and the salt would be unable to remove the blood.

Comment: @mori otherwise, there is no Talmudic basis for this rule. Yet virtually everyone enforces it, throughout the Halachic literature - which is why I mentioned it here as a counterpoint to the assumption upon which the question is based. Not that it disproves anything, but it does necessitate some substantiation of the basis.